# How to validate/restrict values in a column as per a specific format in a sql Database

Tags: sql

I am working on an application that populates values from sql Database in a format two **numeric** and **alpha** character e.g 11G,34H. There is no validation or check for the same.I want to put put checkpoint/validation from Database end.Is it possible to implement via SQL procedure or anything.Can anyone help me with the code.

Comment: Is this SQL Server? You can put a check constraint which will not allow the values to be inserted if they are not in correct pattern. If the objective is to let all values to be inserted and select only those rows which match the pattern then that can be done in the select statement.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Amit. The objective is not to allow insert of values which doesn't match the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below query

```
DECLARE @strtable TABLE (column1 VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO  @strtable
VALUES ('11H'),('sda'),('175HH'),('1H1'),('282')

INSERT INTO YourTable (Column1)
SELECT Column1
FROM @strtable
WHERE LEN(column1)=3 
   AND ISNUMERIC(LEFT(column1,2))=1 
   AND ISNUMERIC(RIGHT(column1,1))!=1

--Output : 11H
```

Comment: A very product specific answer. Which dbms is this for?